# How to find the next diagonal number in the Ulam spiral?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers

[image]

That's the Ulam spiral. I'm doing some programming with primes, and I'm wondering how to efficiently find diagonal numbers.

Basically what I'm trying to do is *for some number $n$, find the numbers that are diagonally next to it on the Ulam spiral.*

For example: in the picture the numbers that are diagonal to $3$ are: $11, 13, 15$, $1$ (there is no reason why I circled just one of them on them on the picture).

---

Since I'm making a program I could just tell the computer to get the $(x+1, y+1)$ number (and other diagonal numbers), but that would be extremely slow with big numbers, so I'm trying to find a mathematical way of doing it.

If you need more info on the Ulam spiral, take a look at this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) or [Numberphile's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFuR97YcSLM) on the topic.

---

The question is: for a number $n$ what are the numbers that are next to it diagonally on the Ulam spiral? (note that there are always four of them)

Comment: Why $27$ next to $11$ but not $29$ next to $11$?

Comment: @NgChungTak Read the question carefully. "(there is no reason why I circled just one of them on them on the picture)"

Comment: This might not be much help, but here goes: if $n$ is an odd square, then the previous and next odd squares are on the same southeast diagonal. If $n$ is an even square, then the previous and next even squares are on the same northwest diagonal.

Comment: This might also be of help: http://oeis.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral

Comment: @Janekmuric, pardon for my text phobia.  By the way, what've you tried?

Comment: @Mr.Brooks Actually, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you want to you can write up an answer, or I'll do it when I have time.

Comment: I'll try, but what I wrote last week still feels more like a hint than a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

My website "primorial-sieve.com" describes "the unraveling of the Ulam spiral". The counterclockwise Ulam spiral with startvalue zero is defined by just eight families of functions.

Take a natural number.
Calculate the (x,y)-coordinates, see "coordinates of natural numbers."
You now know in which  E, N, W or S section your natural number lies.
The  (x,y)-coordinates  then translates into the corresponding n  and  c  value  for  the specific  E, N, W  or  S  family of functions.

Use only the  E, N, W or S families of functions to calculate the natural numbers on the neighboring diagonals.